# Is there any equivalent to a "break" statement in a foreach loop?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, workflow

In a visual studio, SharePoint 2013 declarative workflow, what is the most elegant way to "break" the foreach loop?

Comment: Maybe this could have gone on sharepoint.stackexchange.com, but I'm not having any luck getting answers there.

Comment: I don't think so, as SharePoint declarative workflows do not have code. This is the "ForEach" activity.